# Can't set route with VPN post script since upgrade to Big Sur

Tags: macos, command-line, vpn, big-sur

Since upgrading to Big Sur, my VPN post script has not been firing.  The VPN to which I connect does not allow split tunneling.

I have a simple script in `/etc/ppp/ip-up` that allows me to access things outside of the network while still accessing things in the internal network. It has been working for a while now and ever since upgrading to Big Sur, I have to run the command manually to be able to access external websites/services. It is set to be executable and everything so I don't know what the problem is, below is what that file looks like.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

/sbin/route change default 192.168.1.1
```

If I run the command in Terminal it works, so I'm curious if Apple broke something or changed how it works.

Did something major change with how macOS handles this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same here ... it was working for a while though.

What seems to work is:

```
networksetup -setadditionalroutes <networkservice> [ <dest> <mask> <gateway> ]*
```

To find out the adapter names use:

```
networksetup -listallnetworkservices
```

Example:

```
networksetup -setadditionalroutes "name of your VPN" 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.254 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.254
```

Comment: For your case (where you're changing the default route) this may not be helpful. Also this probably only works for connections that are not managed by a third party client.

Comment: There used to be other ways to run scripts when a NIC comes up - maybe some of them still work in Big Sur. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32354/how-do-you-run-a-script-after-a-network-interface-comes-up/97751 You would only need to ensure that it is only run if your VPN connection is up (ppp0 is up).

Comment: I only did it that way because it worked, on my windows laptop I use at work it does a route change but I couldn't figure out how to do that on Mac so I used the command above which did the trick until Big Sur broke it.